# TSLM and Stationary Data

Tags: forecasting

I’m trying to use TSLM to create a model, do both time series need to be stationary before we use the TSLM, i.e do you need to do differencing to stationarize the TS. According to Rob Hyndman notes the TSLM should take care of that, is that correct?

Comment: Where did I say that? TSLM does not take care of stationarity for you, unlike auto.arima.

Comment: @Rob Hyndman - Thank you Prof. Hyndman for the response. I think I wasn’t clear with my question, per the new update for TSLM function it should take care of the trend and seasonal variables. So my thought that it will make the Series stationary. The reason for my question is that I’m trying to build a model using TSLM and some of the predictors in the series are not stationary so should I make the whole series stationary before using TSLM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any TSLM model, the residuals should be white noise (and therefore also stationary). So just check that the residuals look like white noise (use `checkresiduals()`).

If they are not white noise, you should try a dynamic regression model instead, using `auto.arima()` for example.

If you do use `auto.arima()`, and the residuals are non-stationary, differencing will be applied before estimation.

Comment: Thank you Prof. for your response and I appreciate your help.